# Dovecot migration fails: "[…] specify separator […]"

Tags: migration, dovecot, imap

I'm setting up a new dovecot server ("**A**") and I'm trying to migrate one mailbox from another IMAP server ("**B**", Dovecot as well).

On new server **A** my `dovecot.conf` looks like this:

```
[…]
mapc_host = mailserver.ZZZZZZ.com
imapc_user = YYYY@ZZZZZZ.com
imapc_password = XXXXXXXXXX
imapc_features = rfc822.size
# If you have Dovecot v2.2.8+ you may get a significant performance improvement with fetch-headers:
imapc_features = $imapc_features fetch-headers
# Read multiple mails in parallel, improves performance
mail_prefetch_count = 20
imapc_port = 993
imapc_ssl = imaps
#ssl_client_ca_dir = /etc/ssl
ssl_client_ca_file = /usr/local/share/certs/ca-root-nss.crt
#imapc_ssl_verify = yes
```

The uncommented parts in my `conf.d/10-mail.conf` in **A** are:

```
namespace inbox {
  separator = /
  inbox = yes
}
```

I'm then running the following command on **A**:

```
> doveadm -o mail_fsync=never backup -R -u YYYY@ZZZZZZ.com imapc:

dsync(YYYY@ZZZZZZ.com): Error: Mail locations must use the same virtual mailbox hierarchy separator (specify separator for the default namespace)
```

Server **A** uses sdbox, server **B** uses box and has no separators set (although I think that server **B**'s settings shouldn't matter at this point?
Server **A**'s account ist empty.
I'm using Dovecot 2.2.20 from the FreeBSD ports on server **A**.

Any hint on what I'm missing here? Is there a way to display the separate namespaces and their separators? A config I'm missing?

---

**UPDATE**

I added

```
namespace {
  separator = /
}
```

to `conf.d/10-mail.conf` as @moonhawk suggested (after the first entry).

The output of `doveconf namespace` is empty.

Now I first got this output:

```
> doveadm -o mail_fsync=never backup -R -u YYYY@ZZZZZZ.com imapc:

dsync(YYYY@ZZZZZZ.com): Error: imapc(YYYY@ZZZZZZ.com:993): connect(XX::XX::XX, 993) timed out after 30 seconds
dsync(YYYY@ZZZZZZ.com): Error: imapc: Authentication failed: Disconnected from server
dsync(YYYY@ZZZZZZ.com): Error: Mailbox listing for namespace '' failed: Internal error occurred. Refer to server log for more information. [YYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS]
```

On the next try, I got the first error ('[…]specify separator[…]') again…
The log on the other server shows successful logins but nothing else…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add configurations inside Dovecot's `conf.d/` directory don't forget to add `!include conf.d/*.conf`to `dovecot.conf`to include them!

Answer (score 4):

Have you specified a separator for the default namespace (on "A")?
You only mentioned the inbox namespace.
Use the following to dump the namespaces from your config:

```
doveconf namespace
```

Look at "*seperator = ...*" for each namespace, it should be the same for all of them. Especially look at the default namespace

```
namespace {
  ...
  separator = /
  ...
}
```

Comment: the output of 'doveconf namespace' is empty…

Comment: I added a unnamed namespace with a separator "/". Now the output is: `Mailbox listing for namespace '' failed: Internal error occurred. Refer to server log for more information.`

Comment: it's odd that there is no output.. higher privileges? the output would be very helpfull. Maybe the dovecot namespace section in the dovecot doku helps: http://wiki.dovecot.org/Namespaces ... maybe setting the "list" option in the namespace, or looking at your location settings ... or try "doveconf -n" to see the none default values of your configuration

Comment: I forgot to add `!include conf.d/*.conf` to my `dovecot.conf`. I added the lines directly in my main cons file and now it seems to work. Thanks!